# How to evaluate this infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following infinite series: $$\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{\cos\bigl(A\ln(x)\bigr)}{{x^{B}}}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are some real constants.

For what values of $B$ is the series convergent. And can someone help with a generic formula to evaluate it (when convergent)?

Comment: aah sorry.. editing.

Comment: This converges to $\Re{(\zeta(B+Ai))}$ for $B\gt1$ I'm unsure about the case $B=1,A\ne0$ but it otherwise diverges.

Comment: Thank you. Hoping someone will clarify for that case too.

Comment: It appears to diverge for $B=1,A\ne0$ also.